# Is it possible to have a specific polling URL, to get the HttpSession status, but the polling itself should not extend the session?

Tags: java, session, servlets

Is it possible to have a specific polling URL, to get the HttpSession status, but the polling itself should not extend the session?

The idea is that the UI keeps polling the server, and automatically navigates to the logout page once the session has elapsed.

Also, is it possible to do this with web sockets? Can a HttpSession die while a WebSocket is still active? In that case, I could push the information to the client when the Session dies.

Edit: To be more specific, I would like to know if there is something built-in in JavaEE: If I configure some exception in web.xml so that the a particular URL will be excluded from extending the HttpSession. In case WebSockets being alive doesn't affect the HttpSession, then I can use the open socket to inform the client that the session has ended.

Comment: Your question is way to general. Yes it's possible, it might be something you need to implement yourself or it might be already implemented in whatever it is you're using. Vaadin for example has such an option https://vaadin.com/forum/#!/thread/4911812

Comment: I was just thinking if there is something built in in JavaEE... If I do something in web.xml so that the a particular url will be excluded from extending the HttpSession. Or if WebSocket is excluded from extending the HttpSession.

Comment: Nothing in JavaEE, WebSockets shouldn't have any affect on session timeout so you can use them.

Comment: Thanks... I'll look into WebSockets option.